# Can web programs connect to the localhost ports through the browser?

Tags: firefox, chrome, web

I have to visit some ***untrusted*** and ***risky*** sites with persistent connections.

Suppose there is a ***WebSocket***, ***HTTP/S*** or even ***SSH*** server running on my host. Can the web programs (JavaScript or WebAssembly) that running in Chromium/Firefox connect to them? May be risky to my host?

If they can, how to block such connections to localhost?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Anything in a web page can speculatively link e.g. to `localhost:22` and see what happens.

It seems like quite a leap from there to actually exploiting something; but you might want to run your browser inside a Virtualbox or VMware virtual host to isolate it from the rest of your system. Take extra care to lock down any guest-to-host communications (shared clipboard etc).